# Writing a testable Finagle Resolver

Tags: finagle, twitter-finagle

I'd like to test a Finagle Resolver properly.

Let's get a sample code:

```scala
import com.twitter.finagle.{Addr, Address, Resolver}
import com.twitter.util._

class DummyResolver extends Resolver {

  override val scheme: String = "sample"

  override def bind(arg: String): Var[Addr] = {

    val delegate = SomeFactory.fromArgs(arg).build()

    Var.async(Addr.Pending: Addr)(u => addrOf(u)(delegate))
  }
}
```

The use of a static factory prevents me from unit-testing the resolver.

As far as I know, the only way to provide the resolver to Finagle is to declare it into the `com.twitter.finagle.Resolver` file in `META-INF/services`. Thus, I cannot provide an instance myself.

Given those constraints, how to design the resolver to either:

- be able to provide an instance of the `delegate`,
- or be able to properly test the behavior (and mock the delegate)?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?. I´m really consider leave finagle framework, there´s no documentation and a big community behind.

Comment: No, I did not. What I did is extracting as much code as possible from the DummyResolver class and test that extracted code. The DummyResolver remains un-properly tested.